# VBA code to check each sheet, locate a cell containing =TODAY() function, and select that cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 12 worksheets each named JANUARY through FEBRUARY.

Only the current month's sheet (e.g., NOVEMBER) will ever contain a cell containing the function `=TODAY()` in mm/dd/yyyy date format.

When I open the workbook, I want to automatically activate the Sheet that contains this cell (in my instance Cell `N2`) and `Select` it. I am truly a newbie learning slowly, but knowledge is minimal and can't find what I need. This what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub ChooseSheet()
Dim SearchString As Variant

SearchString = "TODAY()"       'string I am searching for

Do Until SearchString = "TODAY()"
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(14), SearchString) > 0 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
        Exit Do                
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
Sub searchToday()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim found As Range

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set found = sh.Cells.Find(what:="=TODAY()", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
           sh.Activate
           found.Select
           Exit Sub
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong. I needed to tell it what I was looking for in terms of range of cells first, then what in the cell I am looking for, and do that on each sheet in the workbook. THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU Mattboy and Tim.

Comment: How can I get this to run automatically when I open the workbook?  I placed above code(s) into ThisWorkbook module as Private. Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place it under `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` and you're all set!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim f As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set f = ws.Cells.Find(What:="=TODAY()", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            ws.Activate
            f.Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: @mattboy  Yep - only so many ways to do this...  You beat me by 30 sec though.

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong. I needed to tell it what I was looking for in terms of range of cells first, then what in the cell I am looking for, and do that on each sheet in the workbook. THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU Mattboy and Tim.